# Turn `gcloud beta functions deploy` command into a Deployment Manager template with a FailurePolicy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-deployment-manager

I'm running this command:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy myfunc \
--entry-point handler \
--project my-project \
--runtime python37 \
--trigger-resource 'gs://my-bucket' \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

How do I specify xxx and xxx in the Jinja template? Looks like I have to use EventTrigger in the template, but I am not sure how that is formatted?

```
resources:
  - name: resource-name
    type: 'gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions'
    properties:
      function: test
      parent: projects/my-project/locations/us-central1
      location: us-central1
      sourceArchiveUrl: 'gs://my-project-bucket/sdfsd.zip'
      runtime: python37
      entryPoint: handler
      maxInstances: 10
      timeout: 30s
      availableMemoryMb: 64
      eventTrigger: ????
```

Is there a full example of an EventTrigger specified in YAML that includes a FailurePolicy?

Documentation doesn't make this very clear: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#FailurePolicy

Not sure what this is suppose to look like in the yaml template:

[image]

This works for setting a failurePolicy in Jinja:

```
  ...
  eventTrigger:
    ...
    failurePolicy:
      retry: {}
```

Pretty wonky but to disable you just don't specify it:

```
{% if properties['failurePolicy'] %}
 failurePolicy:
  retry: {}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment Manager has some [specific examples on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/google/resource-snippets/cloudfunctions-v1). Here's an example of an `eventTrigger` with Cloud Pub/Sub:

```
eventTrigger:
  resource: $(ref.my-topic.name)
  eventType: providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish
```

For a [FailurePolicy](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.functions.v1beta2#google.cloud.functions.v1beta2.FailurePolicy.Retry), I would try adding this:

```
eventTrigger:
  ...
  failurePolicy:
    retry: true
```

Reference:

- [configurable_functions.jinja#L25-L27](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/google/resource-snippets/cloudfunctions-v1/configurable_functions.jinja#L25-L27)

Comment: yeah but I cant find one with a FailurePolicy

Comment: updated answer. I can't find an exact example in the wild for this, but this is my best guess. let me know how it works.

Comment: in case it's helpful, this is how serverless framework implemented a test for this feature (in JSON, so ymmv): https://github.com/serverless/serverless-google-cloudfunctions/pull/132/files#diff-7fcd34128a89d120d79b9af9da70fa82R564-R570

Comment: Was there any error, or no effect? I'll look into this more and get back to you.